# WebRequest via SQL Azure

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I would like to issue a `HTTP webrequest` from a `stored procedure` in SQL Azure. I know that there are ways to do this on a normal SQL Server, but does it work on azure aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you refer to OLE Automation procedures. It is not possible with SQL Azure. SQL Azure prevents you from calling server resources, it is limited to transactional processing only.